# Div get color and lose on click with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

People

Here I have a JS code for rating (disadvantage, average, advantage) and button for all these parameters.

But I have a problem, when I click on disadvantage, average and advantage button it must lose its color if was clicked before on these buttons, also this is the same if I click on average or advantage because other buttons must lose their colors and only the clicked button to get color. Somewhere is the problem. I put code in one jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwsvP/

```
$(".ca_button, .ca_button1").click(function () {

    $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is("a")) {
        $this = $this.parent();
    }

    $par = $this.parent();

    $par.find(".ca_button, .ca_button1").css("background-color", "#bababa");

    if ($(this).hasClass("ca_button1")) {
        $this.find("a").css("background-color", "#0F0");
    } else {
        $this.find("a").css("background-color", "#F00");
    }

    return false;

});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mwsvP/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the way you define the this variable:

```
$this = $(this);
```

should work better if you do:

```
var t = $(this);
```

And then use `t` everywhere where now you use `$this`.

```
$(".ca_button, .ca_button1").click(function () {

    var t = $(this);

    if (t.is("a")) {
        t = t.parent();
    }

    $par = t.parent();

    $par.find(".ca_button, .ca_button1").css("background-color", "#bababa");

    if ($(this).hasClass("ca_button1")) {
        t.find("a").css("background-color", "#0F0");
    } else {
        t.find("a").css("background-color", "#F00");
    }

    return false;

});
```

Here is your updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwsvP/2/

Comment: please explain in jsfiddle to understand better what you think.THANKS!

Comment: Hued, look in my answer there is a link to jsfiddle with number 2, which means "an update from your version with number 1". I think the required functionality works in my jsfiddle. Also please have a look at the full code that I added to my answer. If you do a copy and paste to your project I think it will actually work as you'd like it to.

Comment: Hued, 3 is indeed the perfect solution. But the code in your question also has no functionality on "average". Since I used the code in your question as the base, the result is that my code does nothing on average either. Anyway, the point here is that your code has the `$this` declaration without the `var` keyword. Also starting variable names with `$` is very confusing in a jQuery context. I pointed you in the right direction by shedding light on the confusion of the `$this` variable. Now it looks like you can fix the rest of the functionality. :)

Comment: Do try, I'm sure the best learning is by discovering things yourself. However, feel free to ask a new question if you come across another specific issue.

Comment: please help just with that... click on average must return disadvantage and advantage buttons to same as on start - so without color.

Comment: i was try to do in 5.version but your 4. version work better, thanks

Comment: yes thanks I integrated your code into mine but isnt work like I need... please see http://jsfiddle.net/SVPY2/1/

Comment: The HTML structure is very different. In my code the classes "ca_button" and "ca_button1" are on `div` elements surrounding the `a` elements. In the combined source those classes now reside on the `a` elements themselves. Therefore the parent is another element. I rephrased and added some comments to my code so you might better understand what actually goes on. Hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/mwsvP/20/